# How to add vertical scroll in HTML DataList tag

Tags: html, datalist, html-datalist, datalistitem, dynamic-data-list

I have a datalist with lot of option, The list goes too long I want to give it vertical scroll.

```
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
<option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
<option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
```

Here the demo Problem
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/co47p87g/)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's not much you can do with the datalist attribute. The datalist does not currently support any CSS styling, and specific visual characteristics are browser-specific. Some browsers may choose to add scrollbars for long lists.
If this isn't acceptable, you may have to forget the datalist and implement a dropdownlist and set the list size as per your needs.

Comment: can you give an example

Comment: @ozil check out your fiddle link in firefox browser the scroll is available